# Mysql where clause with capital letters

Tags: mysql, sql, case-sensitive

Is it possible to check for exact the same String in the where clause of MySQL query.

assuming we have the following table:

```
| id | name |   hash   |

| 1  | toby | abcdefgh |
```

the current query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hash = 'AbcdefgH' # Should return 0 rows
```

would return the same as:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE hash = 'abcdefgh' # Should return 1 row
```

How can i litterally check for the string case-sensitive.

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you. The question you linked to is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY hash = 'AbcdefgH' # Now returns 0 rows